# Know Time a visitor stays on website

Tags: php, mysql, session, analytics

i want to know how much time a visitor stays on my website..??? can it be done with any online services ??..Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Post it on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://emarketing-tactics.com/2011/09/12/how-to-keep-website-visitors-engaged-for-more-than-10-seconds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google analytics http://www.google.com.au/analytics/

A session can only change every time you call set or reset it.
But if you wanted to, you could use jQuery ajax, to run a script every X seconds or mins. Then in the file that you are ajax'ing in. Change your session data.

You will find analytics make a new request every time the user does something. Like moves the mouse, clicks on something, etc. So you would have to set up some js to do that as well.

Comment: just i can get the last activity , but for what condition i update rows  ?